# sudo apt-get install "libgcc1:i386" fails in Juju install hook but working manually

Tags: apt, juju

I am trying to install "libgcc1:i386" through my Juju install hook but the command is failing with the below error:

```
2015-05-26 08:59:23 INFO unit.wxs/0.install logger.go:40 sudo: unable to resolve host suchi-local-machine-26
2015-05-26 08:59:23 INFO unit.wxs/0.install logger.go:40 E: Unable to locate package libgcc1
2015-05-26 08:59:23 ERROR juju.worker.uniter.operation runhook.go:86 hook "install" failed: exit status 100
```

Code in install hook looks like:

```
sudo apt-get install libgcc1:i386
```

But when I try the same command in bash prompt, it works without any errors. In general, `sudo apt-get install` is working in install hook when I try to install other libs.

Environment details:

```
Linux islrpbeixv665 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS \n \l

echo $SHELL
/bin/sh
```

My Juju environment is local.

```
~/charms/trusty/wxs/hooks$ juju status
environment: local
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.22.1.1
    dns-name: localhost
    instance-id: localhost
    series: trusty
    state-server-member-status: has-vote
    "28":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.22.1.1
    dns-name: 10.0.3.18
    instance-id: suchi-local-machine-28
    series: trusty
    hardware: arch=amd64
services:
  wxs:
    charm: local:trusty/wxs-21
    exposed: false
    units:
  wxs/0:
    agent-state: error
    agent-state-info: 'hook failed: "install"'
    agent-version: 1.22.1.1
    machine: "26"
    public-address: 10.0.3.77
```

Thanks